# How do you return a JSON response to a route after a query in MySql?

Tags: mysql, node.js, elasticsearch

I'm using elasticsearch, node, and MySql. I need to sync some user data from MySql to elasticsearch. My route is set up like:

```
router.post("/register_user", (req, res, next) => {
    mysql.register(req.body).then((result) => {
        elastic.createUser(...);
    });
});
```

When a user posts to this route, it successfully creates a row in mysql:

```
const mysql = require("mysql");
const connection = mysql.createConnection("...");
connection.connect();

exports.register = (req, res) => {
    const user = { name: req.name };
    connection.query('INSERT INTO user SET ?', user, (err, rows) => {
        // stuff for errors
        // ...
        connection.end();
        // what do I do here?
    });
});
```

I tried:

```
// I got an error regarding "status of undefined"
res.status(200).json({ id: rows.insertId });

// I got something about "then of undefined" in the router
return { id: rows.insertId };
```

Comment: Looks like you want `register` to return a `Promise`, since you're calling `.then` on the result

Comment: Ah ha! Thanks, @CertainPerformance. That worked.